# List of iOS devices that support compass/geomagnetic field

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, ipod

I am developing an augmented reality iOS app (iPhone/iPad/iPod) and I would like to have a list of devices where this feature is supported.
I mean the compass and the geomagnetic field so that I can get the orientation of the device in all degrees of freedom.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compass is available on all iPads and on the iPhone 3GS and 4.

Comment: As of November 2010, no iPod supports the compass.

Answer (score 0):

I was also wondering if there are any devices left capable of running iOS7 or iOS8 without compass feature and a quick research pointed out the following:

**Compass available:**

- on any iPhone 3GS or later. iOS7 support from iPhone 4 or later, iOS8 support from 4S or later.
- on any iPad. iOS7 and iOS8 support starts with iPad 2 or later.

**Compass not available:**

- on any iPod touch. 5th generation (current model as of 2015) does support iOS7 and iOS8

So if you design an application for iOS7 or iOS8 and only for the iPhone/iPad there will be heading available. For the iPod touch not.

Answer (score -1):

Compass does not provide orientation in all degrees of freedom, although you can get that data from the orientation sensors.

You should also look at the gyroscope (iPhone4 and iPod touch 4 only so far), which provides much more accurate and faster orientation sensing in all degrees of freedom, see [UFO on Tape](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ufo-on-tape/id390109631?mt=8) for an excellent example.

Comment: The gyroscope doesn't sense orientation, it senses movement.

Comment: Apple's Core Motion will calculate orientation for you based on the total of the sensors available on devices with a gyroscope, though.

Comment: The latest iPod touch has a gyroscope.

Comment: it can provide orientation from dead reckoning - integrating over movement.

Comment: The gyroscope cannot help you find magnetic north or any other real-world bearing. It is a different instrument and does not relate to the question.

Comment: but the compass is slow to respond, and only understands one axis.  An augmented reality application will work a lot better if it gets a compass lock and then uses dead reckoning for fine movement as required by augmented reality.  I have used the UFO on tape in both gyro and sensor mode, and the gyro mode is way better.